# Amazon lex unknown utterance to the Amazon Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I would like to know how to call lambda function from missed utterances. I created a bot I want like whenever the user request a query which is not available in the provided utterances, it will go to the error handling, instead of that I would like to call a lambda function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the built-in intent: [**AMAZON.FallbackIntent**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/built-in-intent-fallback.html)

> When a user's input to an intent isn't what a bot expects, you can configure Amazon Lex to invoke a fallback intent. ...
>
> Invoking a fallback intent uses two steps. In the first step the fallback intent is matched based on the input from the user. When the fallback intent is matched, the way the bot behaves depends on the number of retries configured for a prompt. For example, if the maximum number of attempts to determine an intent is 2, the bot returns the bot's clarification prompt twice before invoking the fallback intent.
>
> **Amazon Lex matches the fallback intent in these situations:**
>
> - The user's input to an intent doesn't match the input that the bot expects
> - Audio input is noise, or text input isn't recognized as words.
> - The user's input is ambiguous and Amazon Lex can't determine which intent to invoke.
>
> **The fallback intent is invoked when:**
>
> - The bot doesn't recognize the user input as an intent after the configured number of tries for clarification when the conversation is started.
> - An intent doesn't recognize the user input as a slot value after the configured number of tries.
> - An intent doesn't recognize the user input as a response to a confirmation prompt after the configured number of tries.
>
> **You can use the following with a fallback intent:**
>
> - A fulfillment Lambda function
> - A conclusion statement
> - A follow up prompt
>
> **You can't add the following to a fallback intent:**
>
> - Utterances
> - Slots
> - An initialization and validation Lambda function
> - A confirmation prompt